# What is it called when people decide an issue for you and you have no say in the matter?

Tags: single-word-requests

All powers in Yalta (word) decided the fate of Eastern Europe.

Comment: Who is the “you” in this question?

Comment: Subordinacy? Powerlessness?

Comment: I think it's called loosing a war.

Comment: ‘Parenting’ is one word for it.

Comment: @Phil Sweet As in _Let loose the dogs of war_? Or was it a _slip_?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ops.

Comment: @Phil Sweet Ah, the War of the Ring.

Comment: They acted _dictatorially_. Plus ça change

Comment: The primary document of Yalta was the *Declaration of Liberated Europe* that allowed the people of Europe "to create democratic institutions of their own choice". WRT Eastern Europe and the Soviet Sphere of Influence, following Yalta, in Russia, when Soviet Foreign Minister Vyacheslav Molotov expressed worry that the Yalta Agreement's wording might impede Stalin's plans, Stalin responded "Never mind. We'll do it our own way later." The above text is extracted from Wikipedia article on Yalta, and the sources of the quotes are cited there.

Comment: The participants at Yalta **imposed** their decision on all of Europe.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be:

> #### unilaterally
>
> adverb
>   UK ​  /ˌjuː.nɪˈlæt.ər.əl.i/ US ​  /ˌjuː.nəˈlæt̬.ɚ.əl.i/
>   ​in a way that involves doing or deciding something without first asking or
>   agreeing with another person, group, or country:
>
> - The region is seeking to unilaterally declare independence.
> - The rebels continue to attack from their side of the unilaterally determined border.
>
> [-- Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unilaterally)

Comment: Seems inappropriate for a trilateral conference.

Comment: @PhilSweet not a problem, since the Eastern Europeans weren't one of the parties.

Answer (score 0):

Peremptorily: leaving no opportunity for denial or refusal

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/peremptorily